# Program Crashed (String Manipulation)

Tags: c, string

[Python vs C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R40J6.png)

Program Output is gonna be like this:

```
string1 : stack
string2 : overflow
changed string is : sotvaecrkf
```

*every Nth character of string1 is concatenated by Nth character of string2

But my DevC++ is crashing every time i run and give input to string1 and string2

Code in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void zips();


void main(){
zips();
}


void zips(){

printf("enter string1:");
char s1[120],s2[120],s[120],y,z;
scanf("\n%s",s1);
printf("\nenter string2:");
scanf("\n%s",s2);
int leng,increasedlength,i;
int leng1=strlen(s1),leng2=strlen(s2);
if(leng1==leng2){
    leng=leng1;
}
else if(leng1<leng2){
    increasedlength=leng2-leng1;
    leng=leng2-increasedlength;
}
else{
    increasedlength=leng1-leng2;
    leng=leng1-increasedlength;
}
for(i=0;i<=leng;i++){
    y=s1[i];
    printf("%s",y);
    z=s2[i];
    printf("%s",z);
    strcat(y,z);
}   
}
```

Comment: And the question is…?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're actually asking for here. What's your problem? Also, what do you mean by concatenating? It doesn't sound like you actually want to concatenate your string1 and string2.

Comment: The variables `y` and `z` are *single characters*, not strings, so you can't print them as string or use them in string functions like `strcat`. The compiler should be shouting warnings at you for the code you have, and if not enable more warnings.

Comment: The edit makes it much more clear what the program is supposed to do, but there is still no question here.

Comment: This question was posted in different forms several times today...

Comment: My question is that what is the alternative of s=s+y+z; like we used to do for concatenation and in c it's difficult i don't know what to do??? i am confused..i am new to C.Check Python vs C picture .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like this. Note that string concatenation cannot be done on simple `char` types.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char s1[] = "stack";                            // skipped the string inputs
    char s2[] = "overflow";
    char str[120];
    size_t i;                                       // var type returned by `strlen`
    size_t index = 0;
    size_t leng1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t leng2 = strlen(s2);
    size_t leng = leng1 <= leng2 ? leng1 : leng2;   // ternary operation to get min length
    if(leng == 0 || leng * 3 > sizeof str)
        return 1;                                   // will not fit output string
    for(i = 0; i < leng; i++) {                     // note `<=` changed to `<`
        str[index++] = s1[i];                       // buiuld the output string
        str[index++] = s2[i];
        str[index++] = ' ';                         // pad string
    }
    str[index - 1] = '\0';                          // terminate string
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
so tv ae cr kf
```

Comment: You need `if(leng * 3 >= sizeof str)` to account for the nul character.

Comment: @FredK nope, I over wrote the final unnecessary space.

Comment: @FredK... although you've drawn my attention to the 0 length case, and I have edited to trap it, since writing the final `nul` to `str[-1]` would be *undefined behaviour*

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem feel free to post an answer using `strncat`.

Comment: @WeatherVane didn't read the question properly, thought OP was just trying to concat 2 strings, instead of doing this one-by-one shuffle business

Comment: @WeatherVane the OP's original post says "changed string is : sotvaecrkf" which does not have the added spaces. If that's what is really wanted, the size check would have to be `leng * 2 >= sizeof str`

Comment: @FredK you would be right in that case: but I answered what I saw asked.